# need to fix SVG DOM using jQuery , javascript or any other plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, svg

I'm creating a family tree using SVG, a small structure is given below.
I need help to add specific class(say 'selected') on mouse over on the class - "node", on every first "rect" of "g" which is the parents of the current hovered "node".

> $this.addClass('classname') is not working. So I m using $this.attr('class','classname')
>
> **Impotent : I need a function like parents ( - in jQuery ) or similar methods to get all parent "g" of the current hovered "rect".**
>
> current work - [click here](http://demo.qzion.com/family/pages/tree)

A sample structure.

```
<svg style="width:100%;height:455px" id="svg_root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <g id="viewport" >
        <g id="1">
            <rect class="node" y="0" x="0" width="160" height="35" />
            <text class="prof_name" y="14" x="34">Name</text>
            <g id="2">
                <rect class="node" y="40" x="30" width="160" height="35" />
                <text class="prof_name" y="54" x="64">Name</text>
                <g id="7">
                    <rect class="node" y="80" x="90" width="160" height="35" />
                    <text class="prof_name" y="94" x="94">Name</text>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g id="18">
            <rect class="node" y="120" x="0" width="160" height="35" />
            <text class="prof_name" y="134" x="34">Name</text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I think jQuery is not friendly with SVG :(

Comment: have you looked at [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/). Really nice library for working with svg. Compatible with IE7 and IE8.

Comment: _this is not really help much :( ._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me .

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('#viewport .c_node').mouseenter(function(e) {
        paint_parent(e.target.parentNode);
    });
$('#viewport .c_node').mouseleave(function(e) {
        $('#viewport g').each(function(index, element) {
            $(element).attr('class',"");
        }); 
    });
});
function paint_parent(element){
        if(element.id!="viewport"){ // to the parent id viewport
        $('#'+element.id).attr('class',"cnode_parent");
        paint_parent(element.parentNode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use a jQuery plugin that lets you interact with an SVG canvas. Exactly this one http://keith-wood.name/svg.html (SVG DOM tab)

> The SVG DOM is different to the HTML DOM for which jQuery was
>   designed. In particular, any attributes that can be animated are
>   stored as objects instead of plain strings. This includes the class
>   attribute. Thus, jQuery's functions that work with classes don't work
>   on SVG nodes.
>
> To overcome this problem you can use the jQuery SVG DOM extension.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svgdom.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is poorly documented. Please recommend some functions similar to parents() in jQuery or some other methods to do it.

Comment: if you use keith woods' jquery.svg.js, $('rect').parents() should just work. You only additionally need the dom extension to get $this.addClass('classname') to work, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use raphael.js to add eventhandlers. e.g.

```
var paper = new Raphael( "id", 200, 200 );
var rect = paper.rect( 0, 0, 160, 35 );

rect.mouseover( function( ) {
    // do stuff
});
```

More information and demos [here](http://raphaeljs.com).

A fiddle of how your family tree might work [here](http://jsbin.com/oririx/1/edit)

**UPDATE**

Although Raphael.js does not provide functions to find the parent of a svg element you can still track your family tree by adding custom properties to raphael elements.

I have created an example [here](http://jsbin.com/oririx/3/edit) to show how you might achieve this. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: its not about the mouseover event ( this works fine in jQuery also ). I need the SVG DOM helper functions like parent, parents etc.... in Rahel documentation i can't find some functions that are helpful for me.